# Drop-down options filled from json file in Meteor

Tags: json, meteor

I have a local json file in my client folder that contains information for `<option>`s in a `<select>` tag.

I tried using ajax to fill up `<option>`s but my app keeps crashing.

What is the proper way to get information out of a local json file in meteor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get information from the server you need to use a [Meteor method](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods).

To read local file you need to use [assets](http://docs.meteor.com/#assets).

For example, assuming your file is `/private/options.json`:

**server side**

```
Meteor.methods({
  getOptions: function() {
    return Assets.getText('options.json');
  },
});
```

**client side**

```
var loadOptions = function() {
  Meteor.call('getOptions', function(error, result){
    fillOptions(JSON.parse(result));
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I needed to load labels for the client.

Instead of calling the server, the client can directly perform a HTTP call and retrieve the file.

- Put your file into the `public` directory
- Use the [HTTP API](http://docs.meteor.com/#http) to get your file

`HTTP.get('/yourFile.json', {}, function(error, result) {
  var parsedFile = JSON.parse(result.content);
});`

If you are using Iron router be sure to wait for the result before displaying your page with a `waitOn`.

As the call is asynchronous, it might take some time to get your result.